# Android layout resets after camera activity

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-camera

I am developing an android application where there is an intent where the user fills in a form and takes some photographs. This is then stored as a submission and uploaded to a server. The application works well on my Galaxy Note 8 , however with the Galaxy S3 , the layout resets after taking a photo. I have checked the log cat and I do not get an out of memory exception or any errors. The problem is just that after taking the photo, the layout resets, in other words, clears all the forms EditTexts and photos.

Any help regarding this issue would be appreciated.

***I have tried the following, but still had the problem:***

I added this to my manifest application section:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Isn't onCreate() called for your activity after the Capture intent is complete?

Comment: No, and again, the app works perfectly on my tablet. I'm currently playing around with the dimensions of the images for smaller screen to see if that would make a difference.

Comment: I understand that on a stronger device your activity is not destroyed. But on you should check if S3 does not kill the activity to release more resources for the camera intent to fulfill.